# Using maven to generate an ear file for ADF...?

Tags: oracle, maven-2, maven, oracle-adf

I am noticing that Oracle ADF has its own EAR structure. There is an adf folder created like so, inside the EAR, along with the WAR file and standard META-INF directory is this 'adf' directory:

```
adf
  /com
    /companypackagehere
      bc4j.xcfg
  /META-INF
    adf-config.xml
    connections.xml
```

Must I recreate this using file moves...? And how can I create an Oracle ADF and weblogic compliant EAR with maven?

**edit**: I noticed that when JDeveloper creates said ear file, the source folder layout and the EAR folder layout (as described) are hardly similar. So it is taking various xml files and from various places and placing them in the described layout. How can I achieve this in maven? What plugin(s)/tricks do I need?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with Oracle ADF but I think that you could just put the `adf` directory in the `${basedir}/src/main/application` directory of your EAR module (this is the default value of the [`earSourceDirectory`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/ear-mojo.html#earSourceDirectory) property which points to a *single directory for extra files to include in the EAR*).

Something like this:

```
. 
|-- ear
|   |-- src
|   |   `-- main
|   |       `-- application
|   |           |-- META-INF
|   |           |   `-- application.xml
|   |           `-- adf
|   |               |-- com
|   |               |   `-- companypackagehere
|   |               |       `-- bc4j.xcfg
|   |               `-- META-INF
|   |                   |-- adf-config.xml
|   |                   `-- connections.xml
|   `-- pom.xml
|-- web
|   +-- src
|   `-- pom.xml
`-- pom.xml
```

And packaging this project would result in something approaching this (assuming you don't have EJBs or other libraries):

```
ear-1.0 
|-- META-INF
|   `-- application.xml
|-- adf
|   |-- com
|   |   `-- companypackagehere
|   |       `-- bc4j.xcfg
|   `-- META-INF
|       |-- adf-config.xml
|       `-- connections.xml
`-- web-1.0.war
```

Comment: @Zombies I don't understand the update (very likely because I don't know JDeveloper and ADF) and I'm afraid I won't be helpful behind what I posted. Maybe you'll find more hints in this [this pretty recent thread](http://kr.forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=4256995).